# What is VOLT macro for rendering a <form> tag?

Tags: php, forms, macros, phalcon, volt

In Phalcon one can create a custom form extending `Phalcon\Form\Form`. This class has method called `setAction`, but I cannot find any info on how to automatically render a `<form>` tag with action that I specified.

My form is called `RegisterForm`, and I am passing it to VOLT view like this:

```
$this->view->registerForm = new RegisterForm(new UserModel());
```

In my VOLT template I can use the `registerForm.render('username')` macro to automatically render input field registered in my form.

Is there any macro that will create the following?

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
```

assuming that I've used:

```
$this->setAction($this->url->get('index/register'));
```

in the form definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another day of research, and chatting at Phalcon's Slack channel, I've came to realization that, there is no built-in way of doing what I intended.

Simplest solution is to create a `BaseForm` class that extends `Phalcon\Forms\Form`. Here is an example:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Common\Form;

use Phalcon\Forms\Form;

class BaseForm extends Form {
    /**
     * Creates <form> tag in VOLT view.
     */
    public function startForm($method = 'post') {
        return '<form action="'.$this->getAction().'" method="'.$method.'">';
    }

    /**
     * Creates </form> tag in VOLT view.
     */
    public function endForm() {
        return '</form>';
    }

    /**
     * Pushes all errors to flash container.
     */
    public function error($name) {
        if($this->hasMessagesFor($name)) {
            foreach($this->getMessagesFor($name) as $message) {
                $this->flash->error($message);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

With this, after extending a custom form definition, I'm able to use:

```
# IndexController.php
public function index() {
    $this->view->registerForm = new RegisterForm();
}

# index.volt
{{ registerForm.startForm() }}
{{ registerForm.endForm() }}
{{ registerForm.error('username') }}
```

Comment: IMO this hurts readability of your front end code. What when you want to upload a file with that form, or want to add a class or id to the form tag, or any other property for that matter... You'll end up with an array full of tag properties!

Comment: Lukasz, the idea is looking great. You can even put the method in the base Form class with default options and extend in your custom class with custom options like class, fileupload e.t.c like Timothy mentioned
@Timothy he is using classes that extend the base Form so he can do all the work in the class and leave the template file unharmed.

Comment: @Timothy thing is, that all of attributes should be added in form definition, or as another parameter to function that's rendering the `<form>` element. Class that I provided here is only an example, and, in code, I have it more advanced than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to render a form in Volt:

```
{{ form('products/save', 'method': 'post') }}

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ text_field("name", "size": 32) }}

    <label for="type">Type</label>
    {{ select("type", productTypes, 'using': ['id', 'name']) }}

    {{ submit_button('Send') }}

{{ end_form() }}
```

More info in the [**Docs**](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/volt.html#using-tag-helpers).

You can also check Phalcon's project [**Vokuro**](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/views/session/signup.volt) for more examples.

**Update:** Lukasz asked for a solution to render form tag from custom form element with it's properties. **[Phlacon Form Decorators](https://phalconist.com/Michal-St/phalcon-form-decorators)** is the closest solution to the problem I can find.

Comment: But this solution doesn' use extended `Phalcon\Form\Form` element. This is simply using helpers.

Comment: Hey again, it seems that at this point there is no built in methods for this. Updated my answer with closest solution I can find. Will try to do more research these days and let you know if I find something. Good luck meanwhile!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get home.